# SQL Server listening port not showing in errorlog

Tags: sql-server, tcpip

Does any one know why the port my SQL Server is listening on would not be recorded in my errorlog? TCP/IP is enabled and default listening port 1433 configured.

I have this issue on two servers:

- one with a SQL 2008 configured - I can connect remotely to the instance from the management server using SSMS. However, I am unable to connect from the application I am testing connectivity from
- the other is a SQL 2016 - I can also connect remotely to this from the management server and from the application I am testing connectivity from.

Port 1433 is open on both host machines - netstat -na

I expect to see an entry for listening port in my errorlog, would anyone know why it could be missing?

thank you

Comment: 1st Please check if the database server is reachable from application server. 2nd check what protocol it trying to use to connect to sql sevrer and manage it using configuration manager.  3rd check if firewall is enabled and filtering out the server. 4th check SQL Server Browser service is running.

Comment: SQL Server does not mention port in the error log as is instance has saperate directory and mort, so DBA is wise enough to check what instences error log he is looking at.

Comment: @RajeshRanjan thank you for your time, much appreciated. I have checked all the points you listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing TCP/IP info might be caused if errorlog has been [cycled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-cycle-errorlog-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). Sql Server writes the "server is listening" only on startup, not on error log cycle.

To see if this is the case, open the two most recent errorlogs. For the newest one, one of the oldest entries should contain a message about reinitialising the errorlog.

> The error log has been reinitialized. See the previous log for older entries.

Open the second to the latest errorlog and see if the top entry contain a message about cycling the log.

> Attempting to cycle error log. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.

Note that if you use the SSMS log file viewer, the new entries are on top, whilst a text editor shows the oldest entriest first.

Comment: thank you very much. While I totally agree with your correct answer, in my case, the 'listen' string is not in the copies of the errorlog that I've checked. I've checked a few of them now. I just wonder if there's possibly any other reason why the info is not recorded in the errorlog? Thanks again all the same